# how to use comma in the first line of Cover Letter

Tags: commas

May I ask a question? is one of the sentence below correct?

1. "Dear Dr. James, Department of History Chair, and Selection Committee,"
2. "Dear Dr. James, Chair of Department of History, and Selection Committee,"
3. "Dear Department of History Chair: Dr. James, and Selection Committee,"

Comment: "Department of xx Chair, and Selection Committee. Dear Dr. xx, "

Comment: Dear Kris, I first want to express my appreciation for answering to my question so quick. After reading your response, I thought I need to edit my question in order to clarify my question. Do you mind reading my revised question again, please?

Comment: You don't list the designations after the salutation. Place them separately.

Comment: What do you think about this? Remove "chair of department of history" and simply start the cover letter by saying "Dear Dr. James and Members of Selection Committee, please accept this letter..."

Comment: "Dr. James, Chair, and Members of Selection Committee. Dear Sirs, Please accept this letter..."

Answer (score 1):

If you are in Britain, this is how I would advise you to address the letter:

Dr Richard James, Chairman,

& Members of the Selection Committee,

Department of History,

University of Puddletown.

Puddleshire P56 7YU

22nd May 2014.

Dear Sirs and/or Mesdames,

Please find enclosed my application for the position of Departmental Administrator.

*I would naturally leave gaps between the address and the date, and the date and the start of the letter, but this site's software will not allow me to do that.

Comment: Exactly. The "department of history chair" stuff does not belong in the greeting (i.e., after the *"dear"*) but in the address (usually above the greeting). I would recommend *"Dear Dr. James:"* instead of *"Dear Sirs and/or Mesdames:"*. It sounds less like a form letter, and the other committee members should not be offended by this, especially if you mention them in the address.

Comment: @PeterShor I agree. Or you could say *Dear Dr James and colleagues*.

Comment: *Dear Dr. James and colleagues* is a great suggestion.